# what is the difference between searching directly through a file and searching through a string obtained with the "read()" function

Tags: python, search, startswith

I successfully searched a file using the following code:

```
fhand = open('mbox-short.txt')
for line in fhand:
    if fhand.startswith("From"):
    print(line)
```

But if i try to read the file into the string (`inp`) and perform the same search, I get no output:

```
fhand = open('mbox-short.txt')
inp = fhand.read()
for line in inp:
    if inp.startswith('From:'):
        print(line)
```

I'd like to know why I can't query my `inp` string. Please assume the file size is not too large.
If I can use `len()` to query `inp`, why can't I use `startswith()`?

Comment: Iterating over a string yields single character strings, not lines.  Consider `inp.splitlines()`.

Comment: A major difference is the entire contents of the being in memory at the same time, which makes processing it a line-at-time require an extra step to split them up (which requires even more memory).

Answer (score 2):

This works since the `for` loop is actually reading lines from the file:

```
fhand = open('mbox-short.txt')
for line in fhand:
    if line.startswith('From:'):
        print(line)
```

Here, fhand is a file handle and when you iterate over it, we get access to each line in the file.
Here, line is a string and has a method of `.startswith` which we can apply to check if it startswith some particular phrase.

This does not work:

```
fhand = open('mbox-short.txt')
inp = fhand.read()
for line in inp:                  # wrong this is char by char - not lines
    if inp.startswith('From:'):   # wrong since inp is the whole string
        print(line)
```

`fhand.read()` returns the whole block of text in the file and when you iterate over it returns each single character in the block of text. If you use `startswith('From:')` that will never be true since it is only comparing single characters.

You could 'fix' the second this way:

```
fhand = open('mbox-short.txt')
inp = fhand.read()
for line in inp.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('From:'):   
        print(line)
```

Now you will loop over lines of the string -- not characters -- since `.splitlines()` forms a list of lines.

Comment: @dawg Modified the answer, maybe it will be more helpful

Comment: @dawg Please consider giving feedback on the modified answer